# ARM Assembly: Absolute Value Function: Are two or three lines faster?

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, arm, cortex-m

In my embedded systems class, we were asked to re-code the given C-function AbsVal into ARM Assembly.
We were told that the best we could do was 3-lines.  I was determined to find a 2-line solution and eventually did, but **the question I have now is whether I actually decreased performance or increased it.** (Especially on Cortex-M3.)

**The C-code:**

```
unsigned long absval(signed long x){
    unsigned long int signext;
    signext = (x >= 0) ? 0 : -1; //This can be done with an ASR instruction
    return (x + signet) ^ signext;
}
```

**The TA/Professor's 3-line solution**

```
ASR R1, R0, #31         ; R1 <- (x >= 0) ? 0 : -1
ADD R0, R0, R1          ; R0 <- R0 + R1
EOR R0, R0, R1          ; R0 <- R0 ^ R1
```

**My 2-line solution**

```
ADD R1, R0, R0, ASR #31 ; R1 <- x  + (x >= 0) ? 0 : -1
EOR R0, R1, R0, ASR #31 ; R0 <- R1 ^ (x >= 0) ? 0 : -1
```

There are a couple of places I can see potential performance differences:

1. The addition of one extra Arithmetic Shift Right call
2. The removal of one memory fetch

So, which one is actually faster? Does it depend upon the processor or memory access speed?

Comment: Why not benchmark it. That's the surest way to know the performance difference.

Comment: I would totally do that, but am just being introduced to these concepts. I can request the prof help me with a benchmark but more importantly knowing *why* it would be faster or slower is my goal here. Not sure if Benchmarking shows fetch/execute phase time or register/ALU accesses

Comment: It depends on the implementations. Cores before A8 will probably run your code faster, the shift usually is for free, unless your shift-value is in a register. A8 and newer cores have multiple pipelines which might allow some parallel execution which could make both even in cycles, you could give http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/result.php?lng=us a try.

Comment: @KenW increasingly, (at least with CISC chips like x86), benchmarking is the only sane way to be able to understand performance. (The performance profile is essentially non-deterministic). That said, I know very little about ARM; good luck.

Comment: Something like `tst r0,#(1<<31)\n rsbne r0,r0,#0` doesn't involve shift and only uses a single register.  Maybe there is some case I don't get?

Comment: The reverse conditional subtraction is IMO the way to do it. As ARM status register is updated only optionally, one may be able to calculate the sign bit as a side effect much earlier. In effect rsbne could be considered single instruction method to calculate abs. One can use e.g. `movs r0, variable` to simultaneously load the value from memory and to test the sign.

Comment: Is this question supposed to be about ARM or Thumb instructions? Your professor's solution would work as ARM or Thumb code, whereas yours is ARM-only. If they were only considering Thumb instructions that might explain why they thought it optimal.

Comment: @DavidThomas The Question was about ARM Thumb-2 Instruction set for Cortex-M3, since that's what our LM3S811 uses. Both my instructions and my professors ran on the Thumb-2 LM3S811 with success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dive over to ARM.com and grab the [Cortex-M3 datasheet](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337i/DDI0337I_cortexm3_r2p1_trm.pdf). Section 3.3.1 on page 3-4 has the instruction timings. Fortunately they're quite straightforward on the Cortex-M3.

We can see from those timings that in a perfect 'no wait state' system your professor's example takes 3 cycles:

```
ASR R1, R0, #31         ; 1 cycle
ADD R0, R0, R1          ; 1 cycle
EOR R0, R0, R1          ; 1 cycle
                        ; total: 3 cycles
```

and your version takes two cycles:

```
ADD R1, R0, R0, ASR #31 ; 1 cycle
EOR R0, R1, R0, ASR #31 ; 1 cycle
                        ; total: 2 cycles
```

So yours is, theoretically, faster.

You mention "The removal of one memory fetch", but is that true? How big are the respective routines? Since we're dealing with Thumb-2 we have a mix of 16-bit and 32-bit instructions available. Let's see how they assemble:

Their version (adjusted for UAL syntax):

```
    .syntax unified
    .text
    .thumb
abs:
    asrs r1, r0, #31
    adds r0, r0, r1
    eors r0, r0, r1
```

Assembles to:

```
00000000        17c1    asrs    r1, r0, #31
00000002        1840    adds    r0, r0, r1
00000004        4048    eors    r0, r1
```

That's 3x2 = 6 bytes.

Your version (again, adjusted for UAL syntax):

```
    .syntax unified
    .text
    .thumb
abs:
    add.w r1, r0, r0, asr #31
    eor.w r0, r1, r0, asr #31
```

Assembles to:

```
00000000    eb0071e0    add.w   r1, r0, r0, asr #31
00000004    ea8170e0    eor.w   r0, r1, r0, asr #31
```

That's 2x4 = 8 bytes.

So instead of removing a memory fetch you've actually increased the size of the code.

But does this affect performance? My advice would be to **benchmark**.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another two instruction version:

```
    cmp     r0, #0
    rsblt   r0, r0, #0
```

Which translate to the simple code:

```
  if (r0 < 0)
  {
    r0 = 0-r0;
  }
```

That code should be pretty fast, even on modern ARM-CPU cores like the Cortex-A8 and A9.

In Thumb mode (the only mode supported on Cortex-M3), it actually takes three instructions, since `it` (If Then) is needed to predicate another instruction.  All of these are 16-bit instructions.

```
.syntax unified

  cmp r0, #0
  it lt
  rsblt r0, r0 ,#0
```

Comment: I will test this in the lab when I go next, and benchmark yours vs mine.  If it's faster, then I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: turns out that sadly this does not assemble on Thumb-2, but for arm it would work

Comment: Well, I believe the syntax has changed, it should look like this (wow code in comments doesn't really work?):
`2800        cmp r0, #0;
BFB8        it lt;
4240        rsblt r0, r0 ,#0`